# What is the best strategy to determine the final weights of the model after doing k-fold cross-validation?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, conv-neural-network, image-processing

Suppose we are building a CNN model. After we do 5-fold cross-validation and examine the accuracies and other statistical tests, how do we choose the final weights of the model?

Should we choose the one with the highest test accuracy? Or should we combine them somehow? Or just re-run the model once again with our test and validation sets combined?

I know there are several similar questions here, but I don’t find them clear enough.

Comment: Why are you doing the cross-validation? To tune some HPs or to estimate out of sample performance?

Comment: @gunes to estimate the performance